# getID3 "getid3_writetags" class not found exception when using with laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

As the topic says i get a class not found exception when i try to use writetags class on getID3 Library.
But the class getID3 which is used to analyze files works fine . Only the writetags class get the error .

[github link to getID3 library](https://github.com/JamesHeinrich/getID3)

[Documentation of getID3](http://www.getid3.org/)

Can anyone suggest me a fix ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

fixed issue by updating the composer with this

```
"autoload-dev": {
    "classmap": [
        "tests/TestCase.php",
        "vendor/james-heinrich/getid3/getid3/write.php"
    ]
},
```